# Unable to see JMS messages in WebSphere MQ queue

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to put some messages from a JMS code to a local queue defined in local queue manager. I have defined a local Queue `LQ` in WebSphere MQ and using JMS code to put messages. Am I doing it proper here. I am not seeing the messages in WebSphere queue.

Here is the code:

```
try {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    //set up the Connection Configuration values

    // Set the properties
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "HostName");
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "TEST.JMS");

    //JNDI is Not used Here
    MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();

    MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///LQ");
    MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
    MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);

    long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;

    JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("MQJMSTest "+ uniqueNumber);  
    //MQMessage message =  (MQMessage) session.createTextMessage("MQJMSTest "+ uniqueNumber);


    // Start the connection
    connection.start();

    sender.send(message);
    System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

    //JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
    // System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);

    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
    session.close();
    connection.stop();
    connection.close();

    System.out.println("\\nSUCCESS\\n");

} catch (JMSException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
}
  catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this, you've created a transacted session:

```
    connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

According to [the docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm41210_.htm),

> When an application closes a transacted session, an implicit rollback
>   occurs. When an application closes a connection, an implicit rollback
>   occurs for all the connection's transacted sessions.

A rollback would remove any messages on the queue before they ever became visible outside the application that PUT them.  So I'm thinking you might want to COMMIT the transaction, yes?

```
    sender.send(message);

    // ADD THIS HERE ===========================
    session.commit();
    // ADD THIS HERE ===========================

    System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

    // THE COMMIT MUST HAVE OCCURRED BEFORE YOU CAN GET THE MESSAGE
    // BACK OUT OF THE QUEUE IN THE NEXT LINES

    //JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
    // System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);

    // ===================================================
    // DON'T FORGET TO COMMIT THE MESSAGE ON THE WAY BACK OUT OR IT WILL
    // JUST GE TPUT BACK ON THE QUEUE AGAIN.
    // session.commit();
    // ===================================================


    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
    session.close();
```

PS: Please see the section on [JMS Exception handling](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm35210_.htm).  The JMS Exception is a multi-tiered structure in which it is expected that vendor-specific diagnostics are placed in the lower-level elements.  Only by printing those lower-level elements is it possible to know what the transport layer thinks is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day! I had no clue where it's going wrong as my Exception handling was not appropriate.